# Retrieving source code model elements

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-sdk

I am working on my first VS extension. The goal is to click on a file in the solution explorer that contains a class or an interface and then by using t4 template to generate related class off of it, e.g. code-contracts, or metadata class, or DTO, etc. I successfully created my extension menu (seems to be much easier than with the previous versions of VS - nice!) In the experimental instance of VS I create the simplest command line project with a very simple class with one int property. The first thing that I would like to do is when I right-click on the file, if it does not contain a class or an interface, I would like to hide my extension menu-item. My MenuItemBeforeQueryStatus handler code at the moment looks fairly simple:

```
SourceProjectItem = ((IEnumerable)Dte2.ToolWindows
                                      .SolutionExplorer
                                      .SelectedItems)
                          .OfType<UIHierarchyItem>()
                          .FirstOrDefault()
                          .Object as ProjectItem;
SourcePathName    = SourceProjectItem.Document.FullName;
SourceCodeModel   = SourceProjectItem.FileCodeModel as FileCodeModel2;

foreach (CodeElement2 element in SourceCodeModel.CodeElements)
{
    SourceCodeClass = element as CodeClass2;

    if (SourceCodeClass != null)
        break;

    SourceInterfaceClass = element as CodeInterface2;

    if (SourceInterfaceClass != null)
        break;
}
```

The first three lines seem to be working fine: I get the right path of the file, I get a non-null COM wrapper for the source code model, but after the end of the loop SourceCodeClass is null. What am I missing here, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, of course! A minute after posting the question I realized: I have to recursively hunt for the class or the interface. My loop above is looping only over the namespaces.